# Are there secret dimensions in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have heard you can have portals 
to herobrine,the sky, the past/future, heaven, or to the sun, but none of them worked!

Could you please give me some secret portals that work? I have the latest version of minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: [*Herobrine never has existed in the game*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Herobrine#Existence). His only real existence was added as a joke by Notch with the reference in the update notes

> - Removed Herobrine

Therefore the reference to a "Herobrine Dimension" is also false.

Secondly, a "Sky Dimension" is only a mod that was made to be the opposite of the Nether, which was very popular in the earlier days of Minecraft, and led many to believe it was part of the original game.

This also led to many other mods creating similar mods to alternate "dimensions", like the Twilight Forest, but that's all they are: mods.

So to answer plainly; the only "alternate dimensions" that can be found within the Vanilla Minecraft game are the Nether, and the End.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. The problem is to explain this to every single person saying the opposite, that they exist in VANILLA minecraft and they are just glitched for him or whatever. I'd recommend you to bolden the first sentence and "mods".

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There are no secret portals in minecraft. Expect Sky dimension Which has been removed so yeah.

Answer (score 0):

There are no secret dimensions in vanilla minecraft except the nether and the end.